# this certificate was signed by an unknown authority

Tags: ios, xcode, vmware, provisioning-profile

I need to create ipa file for testing purposes.
I go to Keychian access -> Certificate assistant -> Request a certificate from a certificate authority and create some.certSigningRequest file.
Then I upload that file to customer iOS Provisioning Portal and create development and distribution certificate which I download and install on my vmware mac.
When I select certificate i got message: **this certificate was signed by an unknown authority** 
Here is the image:
[image]

I am confused and don't know what can be wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciate.
Thanks people...

Answer (score 172, accepted):

SOLVED!

The problem was missing apple WWDR intermediate certificate.

We must also install the WWDR intermediate certificate issued by Apple’s worldwide developer relations. It can be downloaded from the portal or directly at 
http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer
Make sure you add this to your keychain as well.

To add the certificate: open your keychain utility software on your Mac computer, then go to <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Import items</kbd>, then select `AppleWWDRCA.cer`.

Comment: NOTE: this may work, but you may also need the G2 cert from: http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ -- http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG2.cer

Comment: THANK YOU! I had been looking everywhere for an issue my problem is I was just double clicking the icon to install it or dragging it in. I needed to go to file --> import to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: The solution is the right import. Double-clicking doesn't help here! Thanks for the instructions !!!!

Comment: THANK YOU! After so many hours of looking, I'm finally uploading my archive!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Turns out that Xcode things the distribution certificates are missing if they are not signed properly and hence I'd been bumbling around for ages. As soon as I installed this certificate, all the others turned valid and I was able to upload the App quickly! :)

Comment: I needed to restart my MacBook Pro after installing the cert.

Comment: Yep, once again, needed to restart my MacBook Pro after installing the cert. Why oh why?

Comment: There should only be one certificate `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority` in the *login* keychain ONLY. Delete all other ones.

Comment: Apple changed the authority once again (from 2 September 2020) and the new certificate to use is this one : https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer

Answer (score 8):

I commented on the accepted answer but figured I'd give a more thorough response.

Generating a Merchant ID certificate for Apple Pay yielded the warning of "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority" on the resulting cert.

Typically the "Issued by" shows "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" -- however, in the case of the merchant ID cert, it was:

"Apple Worldwide Developer Relations CA - G2"

Most answers online point to the [AppleWWDRCA.cer](http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer), however this didn't work because of the issuing authority -- in this case I needed [AppleWWDRCAG2.cer](http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG2.cer). I was able to get this cert from here: http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

Comment: this is for apple pay merchant id certificate

Comment: There is now (since 2 September 2020) a third certificate : [AppleWWDRCAG3.cer](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer).

Comment: I spent like 8  hours trying to figure out a `dyld library not loaded rpath/libswiftcore.dylib` error, being new to iOS dev and swift I figured it was an error related to linking. Nope, found mentions of outdated certs and after installing the WWDRCA, G2, and G3 certs my developer cert said valid and was able to run my swift app outside of simulator.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess when you created/generated certificates the keychain preference does not have below configurations.Please check attached screenshot.I think after making certificates tab of preference according to attached image it will solve your problem.

Best of luck
[image]

Comment: is it solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Today we need v3 of the certificate http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer