# SIGABRT error loading app to iPhone after successful build and past successful deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, dyld

I built an iOS app using Xcode 9 and deployed successfully onto iPhone X running iOS 11.4, but since updating iPhone to iOS 12 and Xcode updated to 10 my app builds successfully but then I get a SIGABRT error stating:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3C7010B7-BC26-4638-AEAF-E3F45108826C/PaintingPortal.app/Frameworks/OmniVirtSDK.framework/OmniVirtSDK
Reason: image not found.(lldb)
```

I've done the following to try and resolve this:

- I checked that OmniVirtSDK.framework is listed in frameworks folder.
- I added to Runpath Search Paths to include $(inherited) and @executable_path/Frameworks.
- I checked OmniVirtSDK.framework is listed in Embedded Binaries.
- I checked OmniVirtSDK.framework is listed in Linked Frameworks and Libraries.
- (I removed and added both of these to be sure they were valid attributes).
- I re-ran clean and build several times.
- I deleted the DerivedData folder, then clean and build as well.
- I ensured AVFoundation.framework was listed above OmniVirtSDK.framework in the frameworks list and also in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries lists, in case order was relevant.
- I ensured "Other Code Signing Flags" under Signing was blank.
- I ensured "Other Linker Flags" under Linking included '_ObjC'.
- I ensured "Strip Swift Symbols" under Deployment was set to 'No'.

All of these were the advice on any related forum entries that I could find, so I now need help to understand what to do to resolve the issue and obtain a successful app launch on my test device.

Comment: Have you looked through the answers over here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771796/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftavfoundation-dylib

Comment: I have read and checked every one of the solutions proposed there and applied in turn each of the changes suggested but without success. The error in the link is slightly different to the one I am encountering, as well, as my error states : "image not found" rather than "no suitable image found" with an alternative potential image at another location.