# Dyld Message- Library not loaded - @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib in iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift

I added some Swift classes to my objective c project. then the project has no build errors but it crash immediately after running.

```
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
```

This is a common issue and I found some solutions, like cleaning project and cleaning drive data. but it didn't work.

Also I should mention that I have 2 targets. One with provision profile the other with developer profile. The one with provision profile crashes.

**When I add the bridging header this crash happens when I remove it from target setting, app works but I cannot use Swift files.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771796/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftavfoundation-dylib)

Comment: @Cristik Thanks. but I checked it and answers didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You need to know two things. 1) What rpath is set to (you want it to include `@executable_path/../Frameworks`) and 2) are the `.framework`s being copied into that folder?

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib)