# dyld: Library not loaded // stat() failed with errno=1 // code signature invalid for

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build

I clean built. And I embed swift standard as this post suggests:
[dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771796/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftavfoundation-dylib)

But still getting:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AppleSauceView.framework/AppleSauceView
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B89AF2A8-9CA8-4602-AE1E-AA31FA526D5A/AppleSauceView_Example.app/AppleSauceView_Example
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B89AF2A8-9CA8-4602-AE1E-AA31FA526D5A/AppleSauceView_Example.app/Frameworks/AppleSauceView.framework/AppleSauceView: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B89AF2A8-9CA8-4602-AE1E-AA31FA526D5A/AppleSauceView_Example.app/Frameworks/AppleSauceView.framework/AppleSauceView'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B89AF2A8-9CA8-4602-AE1E-AA31FA526D5A/AppleSauceView_Example.app/Frameworks/AppleSauceView.framework/AppleSauceView: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B89AF2A8-9CA8-4602-AE1E-AA31FA526D5A/AppleSauceView_Example.app/Frameworks/AppleSauceView.framework/AppleSauceView'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B89AF2A8-9CA8-4602-AE1E-AA31FA526D5A/AppleSauceView_Example.app/Frameworks/AppleSauceView.framework/AppleSauceView: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B89AF2A8-9CA8-4602-AE1E-AA31FA526D5A/AppleSauceView_Example.app/Frameworks/AppleSauceView.framework/AppleSauceView: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B89AF2A8-9CA8-4602-AE1E-AA31FA526D5A/AppleSauceView_Example.app/Frameworks/AppleSauceView.framework/AppleSauceView
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B89AF2A8-9CA8-4602-AE1E-AA31FA526D5A/AppleSauceView_Example.app/Frameworks/AppleSauceView.framework/AppleSauceView: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

[This fixed it for me](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051#issuecomment-580003683)

Just:

1. comment `use_frameworks!` on the Podfile
2. run `pod update`
3. run `pod install`
4. clean build folder on Xcode - `shift + cmd + k`
5. run project

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks had a Problem with the PrimaryFlightDisplay and this fixed it for me :D