# Xcode Archive Error: Missing IOS Distribution Signing Identity For (Name)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

When I try to archive my app, I get this error...

[image: Archive Error Image]

I've been doing a lot of research, but can't seem to figure it out. I've tried everything from revoking and recreating my certificates, and recreating the Provisioning Profiles.

What do i do?

Comment: did you download the certificates to xcode ? also, make sure you're using the right schema for the archive build

Comment: is that new mac system ur trying ?

Comment: I'm using a new mac.

Comment: This answer solved my problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820680/this-certificate-was-signed-by-an-unknown-authority

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35456247/873868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer solved my problem...

The problem was that the certificate was not signed by a known authority.

[this certificate was signed by an unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820680/this-certificate-was-signed-by-an-unknown-authority)

Answer (score 36):

According to the Apple Developer Forums, the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate Expiration expired 2/14/2016.

> ... This issue stems from having a copy of the expired WWDR Intermediate certificate in both your System and Login keychains. To
>   resolve the issue, you should first download and install the new WWDR
>   intermediate certificate (by double-clicking on the file). Next, in
>   the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Make sure
>   to select “Show Expired Certificates” in the View menu and then delete
>   the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations
>   Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate (expired on February
>   14, 2016). Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain
>   Access and be available to Xcode for submissions to the App Store.

**Follow These Simple Steps:**

1. Open Keychain from top menu go to **View > Show Expired Certificates** .
2. Now In Keychain Locate Expired **Apple World Wide Developer Relation Certification Authority** in **Login tab** and **System tab** from left panel and delete it from both tabs.
3. Download Certificate: https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and double click to install it.
4. Restart Xcode.

Comment: Almost missed that - `in Login tab and System tab from left panel` but this sorted it - mark this as the answer! Remember you need to delete the expired one twice.

Comment: I just spend an hour trying to figure out why my Ad-hoc app wouldn't sign. Thank you! This needs to be marked as an answer OP!

Comment: You just saved my sanity!

Comment: Dear God, what a pain in the @... Apple did it again. Don't forget to check your "iPhone Distribution" and "iPhone Developer" Certificates. If you click on them and it says "This certificate is valid" you deleted all the HIDDEN expired instances of "AWWDRCA", if it is still red colored the you missed one.

Answer (score 0):

I spent lots of time due to this certificate.After delete **wwdr** certificate in **login and system** tab problem is fixed