# Uploading archive error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, signing

I'm trying to upload my iOS app archive to iTunes Connect using Xcode, but when I click "Upload to App Store" I get the error:

> Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and
>   failed to do so because of the following issues. Missing iOS
>   Distribution signing identity for _____. Xcode can request one for
>   you.

I'm really confused, because I had just successfully uploaded an archive for the same app about 2 hours earlier, and then I needed to make one simple fix and then needed to reupload the archive, and now I'm getting this error. I did not touch anything else.

I've done everything that I can think of to try fixing the problem, I restarted Xcode, my computer, went to Xcode preferences to click 'Download All' on the provisioning profiles, clicked "Reset" on the iOS Distribution on the same page, downloaded again the iOS distribution profile from the member center, went to the code signing settings in my app's build settings and manually set the release signing identity to the iOS distribution profile, and rearchived several times.

Update: Turns out it's due to the WWDRCA expiring today: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/
There are a lot of other people experiencing the same issue. I was able to temporarily bypass the issue by changing the date on my computer back 1 day.

Comment: i am also facing this issue right now :( did you find an answer?

Comment: nvm, I resolved it from your solution and another solution. Thank you! this worked perfectly for me. In keychain > view > Once I enabled Show expired certificates, there were login and system certs which expired today - February 14, 2016. I was able to delete them and add the WWDR cert from your link. After that it worked perfectly!

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/35406327/5512225

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This certificate has an invalid issuer Apple Push Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The issue is because the Apple WWDRCA expired today (Feb 14, 2016): https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Open **Keychain Access**, and in the menu, click **View** -> **Show Expired Certificates**. Then, delete the expired *Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority* from both the **login** and **System** Keychains. Install the renewed certificate from Apple by downloading from https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and then opening it.

Also, you might need to restart Xcode to reflect the changes. Then, clean and build your project then re-try generating your archive.

[image: Your keychain should show like that]

Comment: This worked for me. I don't get why XCode doesn't work out *not* to use expired certificates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the need to click View -> Show Expired Certificates. I didn't see this in other answers, and this was the saving grace.

Answer (score 54):

Here's statement from Apple.

> Thanks for bringing this to the attention of the community and apologies for the issues you’ve been having. This issue stems from having a copy of the expired WWDR Intermediate certificate in both your System and Login keychains. To resolve the issue, you should first download and install the new WWDR intermediate certificate (by double-clicking on the file). Next, in the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Make sure to select “Show Expired Certificates” in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate (expired on February 14, 2016). Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain Access and be available to Xcode for submissions to the App Store.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37208

1. Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer
   and double-click to install to **Keychain**.
2. Select **"View" -> "Show Expired Certificates"** in **Keychain** app.
3. **Delete** Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificates from **"login"** tab and **"System"** tab in Keychain app.

`Edited by :Jeremy Molayem` **Ensure the new downloaded cert is in both login and system** Default to only system tab will still give error.**

Comment: Thanx i have spent my entire evening to find  a solution

Comment: The "Ensure the new downloaded cert is both in login and system" was what saved me. Thanks.

Comment: The last line saved me to. You have to delete the old certificate and install the new one twice. One selecting the option login in the left side options in the keychain and another one selecting the system option on this left side options too. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

1. Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer
2. Double-click to install it in your Keychain.
3. Then from Keychain, Select View -> "Show Expired Certificates" in Keychain app.
4. It will list all the expired certificates.
5. Delete "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority
   certificates" from "login" tab
6. And also delete it from "System" tab.
7. Restart your Mac

Now your system is ready to upload the App

Answer (score 4):

This answer below is the only one that works. Please mark it as the solution

The issue is because the Apple WWDRCA expired today (Feb 14, 2016): https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Open Keychain Access, and in the menu, click View -> Show Expired Certificates. Then, delete the expired Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority from both the login and System Keychains. Install the renewed certificate from Apple by downloading from https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and then opening it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by installing this "Apple World Wide Developer Relations Certificate Authority" certificate in my keychain: [link](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)

Answer (score 2):

As odd as it may seem, setting the computer's date back one day works.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact same problem and I tried literally everything, I deleted expired certificates on keychain, downloaded the new WWDRCA as others have posted a link to. Edited and re-download my provisioning profile. and then quit xcode opened it back up and cleaned but nothing worked. The only thing that did work for me was changing the date on my Mac to Jan 1st 2016 and it uploaded perfectly! This obviously isn't a permanent fix but I'm on a deadline and it needed to get uploaded asap so hopefully this helps someone in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have renewed your account developer, go to [Provisioning Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/limited) site and renew in developer profile.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and the only thing that worked for me was setting the computer's date backwards as suggested by other responders, I tried downloading the "Apple World Wide Developer Relations Certificate Authority" but no luck.