# Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

since today I have the following error when I tried to create an ad-hoc IPA 
   [image: missing ios]

I've already downloaded the new  AppleWWDRCA.cer and the G2, then I rebooted the mac, clean the project, clean the project folder, deleted the related certificates/profile and reinstall them but the error persist.

And I think is related but all my certificate in the keychain display (null) when I tried to export, copy, etc

[image: null in keychain]

and Here you can see all my apple related certificate + Apple Application Integration Certification Authority not present but valid until 26/08/2017 :
[image]

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35403041/1175050

Delete all the provisioning profiles related to that app & make sure you create new provisioning profile with new CSR.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/35403096/5362916

Comment: like I said in my post I did all this thing but the issue persist :/

Comment: @BryanD Have u checked in keychain certificates are valid or not.

Comment: have you deleted the previous WWDRCA certificate? via View -> Show Expired certificates in Login and System

Comment: @AngelaCartagena you might have save my day, there're 2 invalid certificate. I come back to you if it works (or not :p )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading archive error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397453/uploading-archive-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for)

Comment: @AngelaCartagena thanks a lot, it was the 2 invalids certificate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services It resolves this issue perfectly

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/35456247/873868

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to download WWDRCA certificate and delete old one in your keychain app.https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/