# Missing iOS Distribution signing identity

Tags: xcode, code-signing-certificate

I deleted all my provisioning profiles from my Mac by mistake (`Library/Mobile Device/Provisioning Profiles`). Now, no matter what I do, Xcode gives me this error:

> Missing iOS Distribution signing identity

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be/2241624#2241624

Comment: I'm randomly getting this error today also... Please help.

Comment: Check my answer! @Ibdakine

Comment: I actually tried that (downloading and installing to keychain) but it did not work. Did you have to download both links?

Comment: Just the WWDR, but try both!

Comment: What the hell is going on? Is Apple destroying everyones keychain today??

Comment: Still didn't work for me =\ Anyone else get this to work besides Balazs? @Balazs thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer @lbdakine

Comment: I'll try when I get home. Downloaded every certificate on website but didn't work. If your solution works I will be beyond stoked. Thanks.

Comment: i am having this issue too. downloaded the WWDRCA cert and installed in keychain but still same issue :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397453/uploading-archive-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for

Comment: Replacing the WWDR solved it for me, Thank God I looked on stack overflow :)

Comment: I had to replace the WWDR and then reboot my computer for the fix to take effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This certificate has an invalid issuer Apple Push Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services)

Answer (score 111):

This is the same exact error for an expired Apple cert - though I know it's not your issue, you're the #1 answer on Bing at the moment.

[According to the Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37208), the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate Expiration expired 2/14/2016.

> ... This issue stems from having a copy of the expired WWDR Intermediate certificate in both your System and Login keychains. To resolve the issue, you should first download and install the new WWDR intermediate certificate (by double-clicking on the file). Next, in the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Make sure to select “Show Expired Certificates” in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate (expired on February 14, 2016). Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain Access and be available to Xcode for submissions to the App Store.

[image]

You can get a new cert (which expires February 7, 2023). The AppleWWDRCA.cer is available on the explanation page: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

BTW: it appears this new cert is installed with Xcode 7.2.1

Comment: This worked for me! Although I was on Xcode 7.2.1, it was hard to tell whether or not adding the new cert helped, or deleting the old (expired) cert worked. Either way, this solution took 30 seconds and got me up and running

Comment: Thanks @paul Sturm , 1 upvote is not enough for this answer!!

Comment: Replacing the WWDR solved it for me, Thank God I looked on stack overflow :)

Comment: @Paul Sturm: How did you figure that this was the issue?

Comment: Still getting this issue, although the steps here did make sense and I now have the new AppleWWDRCA file. I have been building my provisioning profiles, etc. manually through the apple dev site - will I have to recreate anything/everything?

Comment: ^ Nope. Problem was cleared up after I rebooted my computer

Comment: worked for me. I just had to delete the old one as the new one was already there (from XCode 7.2.1 perhaps?). As soon as it deleted I restarted Xcode and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Just to add. I had this exact same issue today. I checked Keychain and this certificate wasn't even in there. I downloaded and added it worked. So as an addition, check that this cert is even in your keychain. Unsure of how it would disappear.

Answer (score 50):

Check here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37208

Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and double-click to install to Keychain.

Select "View" -> "Show Expired Certificates" in Keychain app.

Remove Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificates from "login" tab and "System" tab in Keychain app.

Comment: Replacing the WWDR solved it for me, Thank God I looked on stack overflow :)

Comment: Deleting the expired cert from the System tab fixed it for me. Classic Apple BS

Comment: You have to download the new one AND delete the old one, otherwise you will keep getting the error.  Thanks for pointing out how to see the expired certificates!!!

Comment: Definitely must delete the old ones, otherwise it's a no-work. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I needed to reboot my system after this solution

Comment: I used to have XCode but stopped developping for more than 6 months and I installed XCode 7.3 from "scratch". Go to WWDR and just install the cert only works for me

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 13):

Apparently, I was having the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820680/this-certificate-was-signed-by-an-unknown-authority) question, the answer there solved my problem too!! Even though I had my WWDR certificate, re adding to the keychain solved my problem!

**EDIT:** Before doing this, here is what I did:

1. Exit xCode
2. Go to Keychain Access. Delete every certificate which has iOS in it's name. Do the same for keys as well.
3. Open up finder, press Go and press ALT, this will bring up the option to go to your Library. Click on that, find Mobile Devices -> Provisioning Profiles -> and delete everything from there.
4. Go to Member Center and revoke every certificate you have, delete all existing provisioning profiles.
5. Open xCode, open your project and in General select your team, under it you will get a warning and a button which says fix issue, click on that. After it is done, build your app to a real device(not simulator) and exit xCode.
6. Go to Member Center and go to Certificates, you will see that xCode has created a new one. Download that, and add it to your Keychain Access.
7. Add WWDR to Keychain Access.
8. Try archiving, it should work now!

**Note:** In Build Settings set code signing to automatic.

Comment: Including Push Services certificates?

Comment: Good question, I did not have those so I do not know. I think those don't matter so just leave them there. The main thing is probably the iOS Distribution Certificate

Comment: Hey Balazs. I was too scared to "delete" my profiles so I kept searching and found this link. You were correct that the new certificate had to be downloaded, but the old one simply had to be deleted as outlined here. The bottom answer is the correct answer. I commented on it. Thanks again for the help!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services

Comment: Replacing the WWDR solved it for me, Thank God I looked on stack overflow :)

Answer (score 9):

It says very clearly. I just had to delete expired certificate as described below and download new one from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer). It is all described on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/).

> What should I do if Xcode doesn’t recognize my distribution
>   certificate? If you have a copy of the expired WWDR Intermediate
>   certificate in both your System and Login keychains within the
>   Keychain Access application, your certificates may appear as invalid
>   and not be recognized by Xcode. To resolve the issue, you should first
>   download and install the renewed certificate. Next, in the Keychain
>   Access application, select the System keychain. Select 'Show Expired
>   Certificates' in the View menu and then delete the expired version of
>   the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority
>   Intermediate certificate. Your certificates should now appear as valid
>   in Keychain Access and be available to Xcode.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:
Keychain Access -> View -> Show Expired Certificates

then

Keychain Access -> System tab

Locate the **EXPIRED** "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority" certificate and delete it.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Answer (score 5):

From Apple -

> Thanks for bringing this to the attention of the community and
>   apologies for the issues you’ve been having. This issue stems from
>   having a copy of the expired WWDR Intermediate certificate in both
>   your System and Login keychains. To resolve the issue, you should
>   first download and install the new [WWDR intermediate certificate](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer) (by
>   double-clicking on the file). Next, in the Keychain Access
>   application, select the System keychain. Make sure to select “Show
>   Expired Certificates” in the View menu and then delete the expired
>   version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate
>   Authority Intermediate certificate (expired on February 14, 2016).
>   Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain Access and be
>   available to Xcode for submissions to the App Store.

Also answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401483/921358

Answer (score 3):

First: down and install WWDR in here https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/
Then: In Keychain Access click View and select show expired Certificates and delete them on login and System tab
Finally: Clear and Build project on Xcode

I uesed above ways to create ipa file. Hope help you.