# Failed to locate or generate matching singing assets Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I have just restarted my Mac and I'm having this error when trying to validate or upload to de Apple Store.

> Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets:
>
> Xcode attemped to locate or generate matching signing assets and
>   failed to do so because of the following issues:
>
> Missing iOS Distribution signing identiti for xxxxxx Xcode can request
>   one for you.

[image]

I have tried a lot of anwsers from Stackoverflow and nothing is working.

How can I tell Xcode to request it again?? I have gone to prefferencens and clicked "reset", "download all", I have deleted de account an logged again.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have u checked in keychain that your certificates are valid or not?

Comment: check this one.It may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/35403096/5362916

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to all.

The answer is here:

[Missing iOS Distribution signing identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398083/missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity)

As Evana said:

> Check here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37208
>
> Download
>   https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and
>   double-click to install to Keychain. Select "View" -> "Show Expired
>   Certificates" in Keychain app. Remove Apple Worldwide Developer
>   Relations Certificate Authority certificates from "login" tab and
>   "System" tab in Keychain app.

I did not dowloaded the certificate but in my machine there were 2 of the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate" and one of them expired yesterday.

I hope this will be useful to someone.

If some administrator thinks the question must be deleted just ask me and I will delete it.

Again thanks to all.

Comment: It helped me, its useful. thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I had added the new certificate but it mysteriously failed until the expired certificate was deleted.