# Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets XCode 7.3.?

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7.3, enterprise-distribution

[image]

So far I have check and done:

- Checked my acc permission on the enterprise dev account: I am the admin and I can create manually profiles
- Deleted derived data from Xcode

  - Delete all provisioning profiles manually
  - Restarted XCode and deleted all certificates from iTunes and my machine
  - Checked my password for the account
  - Changed different app IDs and different projects

I have no clue what I could try anymore. This has been happening since Xcode 7.3.

This solution does not work for my problem: [Same error - different error description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404953/failed-to-locate-or-generate-matching-singing-assets-xcode-7-2-1)

**Update 1 - 14.04.2016.**

- Revoked my developer account permission from ADMIN to MEMBER , and from MEMBER to ADMIN by the account owner - the Agent
- Exported and Imported my development account and profiles for Xcode
- Set **Don't code sign** in Xcode
- Changed developer profiles
- Filled a bug report #25722969

Still no progress.

Comment: You do sure that don't help you？I have the same error with you. But that helped me.

Comment: It worked once, since I updated it. Now I have the same problem.